# Python: scrape a Javascript line

Tags: javascript, python, json, web-scraping

I want to scrape a Javascript line that contains JSON data in Python. For example:

```
AH4RSearch.listingsJSON = $.parseJSON('{"properties":[{"Price":3695,"PriceFormatted":"3,695","Street":"9251 E Bajada Road"}');
```

I understand that after I can get the content of `$.parseJSON` I can use `json.loads` to store it in JSON format, but how do I get this content from the Javascript line?

Comment: it is only string/text so use standard string functions like `split()` and slicing `[start:end]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need `re` to extract the data out

```
import re
import json
your_js_string = """AH4RSearch.listingsJSON = $.parseJSON('{"properties":[{"Price":3695,"PriceFormatted":"3,695","Street":"9251 E Bajada Road"}');"""

m = re.search(r'\$\.parseJSON\(\'(.*?)\'\);', your_js_string)
print json.loads(m.group(1))
# oh, no, your json is broken
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python it is only string so use standard string functions - like `split()` or slicing `[start:end]`.

```
import json

text = '''AH4RSearch.listingsJSON = $.parseJSON('{"properties":[{"Price":3695,"PriceFormatted":"3,695","Street":"9251 E Bajada Road"}]}')'''

data = json.loads(text[39:-2])

print(data['properties'][0]['Price'])
```